# Function to check DNS server

Tags: java, dns

Does Java has similar PHP function checkdnsrr ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [`InetAddress.getAllByName`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAllByName%28java.lang.String%29) although it doesn't allow you to specify the record type.

If that's not enough for you, there are third party libraries around - the first one I found was [dnsjava](http://www.dnsjava.org/).